# Given $A\subset [0,1]$ prove that $m^*(\{1-x:x\in A \})=m^* (A)$

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

Given $A\subset [0,1]$ prove that $m^*(\{1-x:x\in A \})=m^* (A)$.

($m^*$ is outer Lebesgue measure)

---

$$m^*(\{1-x:x\in A \})=\inf\{m^*(G):\{1-x:x\in A \}\subset G \mbox{ and } G \mbox{ is open}\}=\inf\{m^*(1-G):A\subset 1-G \mbox{ and } 1-G \mbox{ is open}\} \ge m^*(A)$$

I don't know how to prove the other inequality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $A \subseteq [0,1]$ let $S(A) = \{1-x \mid x \in A\}$. The statement is that $m^*(S(A)) = m^*(A)$, and you have already shown that $m^*(S(A)) \geq m^*(A)$.

Notice that $S^2(A) = A$ for every subset $A \subseteq [0,1]$, and thus
$$
 m^*(A)
= m^*(S(S(A)))
\geq m^*(S(A))
\geq m^*(A),
$$
so we already have $m^*(S(A)) = m^*(A)$.